# ASP.NET Webmail Client

Tags: asp.net, email, calendar

does anyone knows a free paid webmail client for asp.net that enables me to edit the sourcecode and re-sell it?

I found [After Logic](http://www.afterlogic.com/webmail-client), which is great by the way, but they told me "Currently, we don't offer developer licenses for WebMail Pro".

webmail+calender solution would be great!

tks for any help,
Vitor

Answer (score 3):

plenty of open sources out there.

example:

> http://anmar.eu.org/projects/sharpwebmail/

plenty of paid solutions out there.

example:

> http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/webmail/

Just [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ASP.NET%20Webmail%20Client) it, this is a Developer Site, not 'what components I can get' site

Answer (score 0):

AfterLogic does offer royalty-free developer licenses for WebMail Pro. Just not directly from the web site (as you must first confirm you won't develop a competing software). You can contact AfterLogic for further details.

If you just need to edit the source code but have no plans to re-distribute the modified software to third parties (i.e. all you need is to run the software on your server), that's allowed by any license.

In other words, all licenses are developer licenses (but not all are royalty-free).